# How do I stop a button from triggering when the enter key is pressed? (focused)

Tags: vb.net, forms, button, focus

(I would say hello here, but Stackoverflow always removes it for some reason)
My problem is that on my Visual Basic form the button that I use to close the form can be triggered by the enter key. This is a problem because my form opens a webpage that frequently uses forms, meaning that the enter key on a form will close the window!
Therefore, I need to find a way of stopping the focus on this button. It is a custom-ish button and is its own class but inherits from a normal button. Here's some diagrams:
Stage 1: Before the user focuses on the WebKitBrowser
[image: Stage 1: Before the user focuses on the WebKitBrowser]
Stage 2: After the user focuses on the WebKitBrowser
[image: Stage 2: After the user focuses on the WebKitBrowser]
As you can see, the button is "focused" with a white border, similar to a normal Windows button where the border is instead blue. If I was to press enter at this stage, the form would close.
In conclusion, or TL;DR, how do I stop my close button from being focused?

Comment: Try adding `TabStop =  False` to your close button when your form loads. I think  focus is a result of the button included in the tab order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button by default is included in the tab order which results in the focus effect.

Try removing the button from the tab order. You can do by setting the `TabStop` of your button to `False` when your form loads. I tried the example below and it worked for me.

**Before**

Code:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

**After**

Code:

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Button1.TabStop = False
End Sub
```

End Class

[image]